# How to use cursors in stored procedure?

Tags: java, database, stored-procedures, plsql

I am currently working on PL-SQL store-procedures, So from the Application(REST app) I am sending few IN parameters to Store_procedure and in procedure I am parsing some of the inputs and there are few fields having IN OUT parameters and few of them are cursors in that.

It was existing procedure which is getting use by legacy app which is in xml. All I am doing is added a new REST layer into that.

Now I'm getting this **Exception**:

```
"SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 1111; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111]"
```

I did check all the columns and all but still not able to make it to success. 
I also trying to map thing when response will come back.

Thanks in advance.

I have to execute a stored procedure with has 13 parameters. There are input, output and input/input parameters. 
I am calling the stored procedure from a Spring Boot Java web service. The stored procedure throws an exception:

```
 SQL state [99999]; error code [17023]; Unsupported feature: sqlType=-10;
```

When I use an input/output parameter that is a reference cursor. (I created a store procedure for input, output, or in/out parameters that are of type string or integer and it works fine. But it is the cursor that is the problem.

This is the code that calls the stored procedure:

````
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameterSource.addValue("p_input_stream", input);
parameterSource.addValue("p_cur", null);

simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName(PACKAGE).withProcedureName(PROCEDURE_TEST);
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(
    new SqlParameter("p_input_stream", OracleTypes.VARCHAR), 
    new SqlInOutParameter("p_cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new LoadCursorMapper()));
result = simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameterSource);```

I am using the ResultSetExtractor interface to map the result set for the cursor. This is the class:

public class LoadCursorMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<LoadCursor> {

    public LoadCursor extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

         LoadCursor trailer = new LoadCursor();
         trailer.setTrlrNbr(resultSet.getBigDecimal("trlr_nbr"));
         trailer.setTrlrPrefix(resultSet.getString("trlr_prefix"));           
         trailer.setCatgoryCodeLoadCondStat(resultSet.getString("catg_code_load_cond_stat"));
         trailer.setDetailCodeLoadCondStat(resultSet.getString("detl_code_load_cond_stat"));

        return trailer;
    }
}
````

I am not sure if the way I am declaring the cursor parameter is correct. This code particularly

```
new SqlInOutParameter("p_cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new LoadCloseSummaryTrailerCursorMapper()));
```

When running the service, I get the error:

```
SQL state [99999]; error code [17023]; Unsupported feature: sqlType=-10;
```

Comment: If you want our help, you will have to show us the signature of the stored procedure you're calling, i.e. the declared parameters, and show us how you're currently trying to call it from Java.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for your response. I updated the question for you. Please take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to add the the return resultset to the call and declare all the cursor output field names in the **Result** class.

```
simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName(PACKAGE).withProcedureName(PROCEDURE_TEST)
.declareParameters(
new SqlParameter("p_input_stream", OracleTypes.VARCHAR), 
new SqlInOutParameter("p_cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR))
..returningResultSet("p_cur", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Results.class));
```